# Interface injection with an entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, projection

I have 2 entities: Book and Country

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String mdmName;
}

@Entity
public class Country {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String mdmName;
}


public interface BookCountry {
    Book getBook();
    String getCountryName();
}
```

There is no relation between them. I fetch a list of books and name and country of the book

```
@Query("select book, c.name from Book book join Country c on c.mdmName = book.mdmName")
List<BookCountry> findBookAndCountryName();
```

I want to create an interface project to fetch the List of books and the name of the country, when I get the book from the query it returns null. How do we get the Book from an interface projection?